# Составить регулярное выражения что бы не было некоторых слов

Tags: javascript, python, регулярные-выражения

Делаю упражнения по регулярным выражениям. Надо составить регулярное выражение *that matches all the items in the first column (positive examples) but none of those in the second (negative examp*les).

```
| Positive | Negative |
|----------|----------|
| pit      | pt       |
| spot     | Pot      |
| spate    | peat     |
| slap two | part     |
| respite  |          |
```

Допустим, первая часть будет такая:

```
regex = r'pit|spot|spate|(slap two)|respite'
```

А как вторую сделать и совместить все?

Comment: Переведите сообщение на русский язык, всё-таки SO на русском.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, это одна из обычных задачек на регулярки.

Если я прав, то вы неверно поняли задание. На самом деле нужно создать не регулярку, которая перечисляет в себе исходные слова. Вам нужна регулярка, которая обращается к общим закономерностям в первой колонке, но не настолько общая, чтобы срабатывать на слова из второй колонки.

Таким образом вам нужно это:

```
[\w]*[p].[t][\w]*
```

Comment: Или `\w*p.t\w*`